# How to understand who created a Redshift user?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Given the list of Redshift users in a Database, I am interested to know who created a specific user (which user created which).

Is it possible to retrieve such information?

Comment: check select * from STL_UTILITYTEXT

Answer (score 0):

The table [STL_USERLOG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_USERLOG.html) gives information about users creation. In particular are interesting the columns `pid` (Process ID) and `recordtime` (Time in UTC that the query started):

```
select *
from STL_USERLOG;
```

unfortunately does not give information about who executed the query. For this reason may be useful to join it with [STL_QUERY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) based on the column `pid`:

```
select *
from STL_USERLOG join STL_QUERY on stl_query.pid = stl_userlog.pid;
```

STL_QUERY's column `userid` should reveal who executed the create query.

In my case I had not luck with this approach. But looking into [STL_SESSIONS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_SESSIONS.html) helped me to shrink the potential users who could have created the user of interest. I looked into the sessions which were active at the `recordtime` (STL_USERLOG) the user was created with this query:

```
select *
from stl_sessions
where starttime < '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000' and endtime > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue! I found this repost useful: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/logs-redshift-database-cluster

Following the advice in the post, I joined the svl_statementtext with pg_user.

```
select
    usr.usename,
    st.userid,
    st.xid,
    st.pid,
    st.label,
    st.starttime,
    st.endtime,
    st."sequence",
    st."type",
    st.text
from
    pg_catalog.svl_statementtext st
join pg_catalog.pg_user usr on
    usr.usesysid = st.userid
where
    text ilike 'CREATE%_USER%'
    and type = 'UTILITY'
```

I used ILIKE find the the case insensitive string that started with CREATE USER with any number of spaces between the words.

Be aware that the SVL_STATEMENT view reads internal temporary tables, on our redshift instance the data is available for the previous 7 days.